# composer won't run due to phpunit

Tags: magento2, composer, phpunit

Struggling to update or do anything with composer and get the same error every time:

```
  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
  "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 15:
        "phpunit     ": {re
  ----------------------^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', '}'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the fault of PHPUnit, but your composer.json is broken. As the error message tells you,

```
"phpunit     ": {re
                ^
                |
         here is the error
```

Actually, the whole line and probably more after it  is invalid. The package name for PHPUnit is `"phpunit/phpunit"` and not `"phpunit     "` and `{re` (and whatever follows) is not even close to a version constraint which is expected here (like `"4.1.0"`)

Since you did not show your composer.json, I can only guess that you accidently deleted a part of the file.

Compare it with this one: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/composer.json